# React Printing API Data inside Table

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to display data returned from an API call.. API returns something like:

```
{"id":,"firm":"","office":"","salesCode":"","account":""}
```

and I have a class like this:

```
    const DataConstructed = items.map((item) =>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>{items.data.f}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{items.data.o}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{items.data.s}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{items.data.a}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            );

 render() {
        const { classes } = this.props; 
        const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
          } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
          } else {

            const DataConstructed = () => {
                var data = [];

                for(let i=0; i<items.data.length; i++)
                {
                    data.push(
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>{items.data[i].f}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{items.data[i].o}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{items.data[i].s}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{items.data[i].a}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    );
                }
                return data;
            }

            return (
              <Fragment> 
                  <Paper className={classes.Table}>
                    <Table>
                        <TableHead className={classes.TableHeader}>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>F</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>O</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>S</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>A</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {this.DataConstructed()}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </Paper>
              </Fragment>
            );
          }
    }
```

I get an error saying "TypeError: this.DataConstructed is not a function", I don't understand what the problem is..?

......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not define your class functions inside your render method.

In your case its just a regular function defined in your render method.
You could still make it work.
Just remove 'this' from this.DataConstructed as its not a class function.

```
<TableBody>
   {DataConstructed()}
 </TableBody>
```

Comment: I moved DataConstructed out and changed the call inside render method to {DataConstructed()}, still no help...

Comment: Dont move it outside. You can make it work by just removing the 'this'

Comment: I did it, doesn't work. gives an error on items.map.. @varoons

Comment: You dont have a map function in your code snippet.Please update. If its comingfrom your state , does it have a default. The items array might not be set(due to some async action) which is why it might be undefined. You need to set a default

Comment: .map is a function within react, that I know of?! But it only works for Arrays, so I don't know what I can do to print my JSON row by row.

Comment: I am aware of that but where are you using the map function? Its not in your code! (FYI Its not specific to React but JS)

Comment: items is in your state. you are doing items,map instead of this.state.items.map

Comment: This doesn't work either.. const DataConstructed = this.state.items.map((item) => saying TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function

Comment: this.state.items.data.map

Comment: It's saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefine"... Can you update your answer so I can use that? Maybe I do something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

```
<TableBody>
    {this.DataConstructed()}
</TableBody>
```

Fix:

```
<TableBody>
    {DataConstructed(items)}
</TableBody>
```

Comment: didn't fix it, says items.map is not a function. I believe this is because its a JSON file and .map accepts array.. I don't know how to fix it though @Danyal Imran

Comment: @Extelliqent pass the items array into the function then, check the updated answer.

Comment: items is an object array response got from an API call. I do have an access to it through "items" and I have that written as items.map but it won't work since items is not exactly an array...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it like below. It might not be the best way to address this kind of scenario, but it does the job.

Below code goes under the class but outside of render
    TabularData(items) {
        var elements = [];

```
    for(let i=0;i<items.data.length;i++)
    {
        elements.push(
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>{items.data[i].f}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{items.data[i].o}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{items.data[i].s}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{items.data[i].a}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        );
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Below code goes inside render

```
{this.TabularData(items)}
```